# Иконка окна в Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, icon

Хочу добавить иконку окна в tkinter так, чтобы её использовали **одновременно** два **работающих** окна, как можно такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, для этого Вы можете использовать метод `iconbitmap()` для установки иконки окна для каждого из создаваемых окон:

```
from tkinter import *

root1 = Tk()
root1.iconbitmap('path/icon.ico')

root2 = Tk()
root2.iconbitmap('path/icon.ico')

mainloop()
```

Comment: Благодарю, всё получилось!